# C++ Storing a linked list inside a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, polymorphism

```
Class abstractClass
{
   int variable1;
   string variable2;
   public:
      abstractClass():variable1(0),variable2(""){};
      abstractClass(int variable1,string variable2)
      :variable1(variable1),variable2(variable2){};
      virtual void show() = 0;  
}

class SubClass : public abstractClass // one of the derived class
{
   string variable3;
   public:
      SubClass():variable3(""){};
      SubClass(int variable1,string variable2,string variable3)
      : abstractClass(variable1,variable2),variable3(variable3){};
      void show() {...}
}

class Problem
{
   int number;
   string name;
   LList<abstractClass*>a_list; // linked list of the abstractClass
   public:
      Problem():number(0),name(""){}; //how to initialize the linked list?
      Problem(int number,string name,LList<abstractClass*>a_list)
      :number(number),name(name),a_list(a_list){};
      void addList();
}

void addProblem(LList<Problem>p_list)
{
   p_list.enter(1,Problem(1,"TESTING",...));
   // For the ... is to enter a linked list of SubClass objects
}
```

My problem for this is entering multiple linked list of derived class 'SubClass' inside each p_list

I've tried

```
a_list.enter(1,Subclass(111,"AAA","BBB"));
```

But this gave me error. Do I need to do upcasting for abstractClass and Subclass in order to overload the subclass variables? Or is there another way to do this?

Previously I have tried entering a Linked list of subclass without putting the Linked List of abstract class inside the parameter.

```
Problem(int number,string name):number(number),name(name){};
LList<Problem> p_list(1,Problem(1,"NAME"));
```

This had given me no problem, but I have no idea how to insert a linked list within a linked list.

Comment: Perhaps more meaningful names is a good idea

Comment: In addition to the list problem, this `class Classes: public Student` says that `Classes` is a kind of `Student`. Doesn't look right to me. A student might *attend* classes, but the they are really not the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LList<abstractClass*>a_list;
```

This says `a_list` is a list of *pointers to `AbstractClass`*.

```
a_list.enter(1,Subclass(111,"AAA","BBB"));
```

This says you want to add *an object of type `Subclass`* to `a_list`.

C++ isn't good at guessing what the programmer really wants deep inside. If you have a list of pointers, and you want to add something to it, it better be a pointer. One way to do this is

```
a_list.enter(1, new Subclass(111,"AAA","BBB"));
```

This will work because a pointer-to-`Subclass` can be automatically converted to a pointer-to-`AbstractClass`.

Bear in mind that having a list of raw pointers necessitates managing their memory by hand. A list of `std::unique_ptr<Problem>` is much better in this regard. While we're at it, why not use `std::list` instead of a homebrew list?

**Additional note**. You are trying to pass your lists by value.

```
addProblem(LList<Problem>p_list)
```

This probably isn't going to work well, as `addProblem` with work with a *copy* of your list, and destroy it before returning. You may want to change it to use call by reference:

```
addProblem(LList<Problem>& p_list)
```

Comment: Disclaimer: The answer is based on my rather educated guess, but it's a guess nevertheless. To eliminate guesswork, include a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: This had solved my problem for the linked list pointer for the a_list
But one of my other problem I had mentioned inside the question was adding a linked list inside one of the data of a linked list.

a_list.enter(1, new Subclass(111,"AAA",BBB"));

To add this into p_list = p_list.enter(1,"TESTING,a_list), what kind of function do I need to call?
For example : addProblem(LList<Problem>& p_list, LList<abstractClass*>a_list)

Comment: It is not clear what your other problem is. Are you getting any errors or unexpected output? Please read [mcve].